# Java Multiplication

Tags: java

How will do a program that displays a multiplication table based on the size that the user inputs? And will add each row and each column? Something like this:

```
Enter a number: 4
1   2   3   4   10  
2   4   6   8   20
3   6   9   12  30
4   8   12  16  40
10  20  30  40
```

I tried this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int x = s.nextInt();
for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++)  
{  
    for (int j = 1; j <=x; j++)  
    {  
        System.out.print((i*j) + "\t");  
    }  
    System.out.println();  
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter a number: 4
1   2   3   4   
2   4   6   8   
3   6   9   12  
4   8   12  16
```

How I will do to add each row and each column?

Comment: i would recommend using arrays

Comment: If it's always a square, the numbers on each row/col will be the same.  So maybe just keep a total (maybe in an array) when you're drawing each row?  Then, on the last row, just draw out that array you built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter size of table: ");
int x = s.nextInt();
int r = 0;
int l = 0;
int f = 0;
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){    
    for (int j=1; j <=x; j++)
    {
       r = r + j;
       System.out.print(i*j+"\t"); 
    }
    System.out.print(r);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    l=l+i;
}
for(int k = 1; k<=x;k++)
{
f=f+l;
System.out.print(f + "\t");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like homework, I wouldn't feel comfortable writing your code for you.  However, keep the following things in mind.

1. Your matrix will always be a square, as the user only enters a single number, of `n` x `n` numbers.
2. Since these numbers increment by one along the row and column, the sum of each row and column pair will be the same.  In other words, the total of *row[n]* will equal the total of *column[n]*.

Using that, you can create a single array of size `n` to store the sum of each row.  For example:

```
Enter a number: 3
1   2   3   x
2   4   6   y
3   6   9   z
x   y   z
```

When you're looping through each row, you can store the row total in the array.

```
Row 0: Add 1 + 2 + 3 and store in array[0]
Row 1: Add 2 + 4 + 6 and store in array[1]
Row 2: Add 3 + 6 + 9 and store in array[2]
```

At the end of *each row* you can simply display the total in `array[row]`.  When you finish drawing *all rows*, you'd simply loop through `array` and display each total value.

Hope this points you in the right direction!